# My system still boots from the key i installed how can stop and makes it boot from hard disk drive

Tags: kernel

Sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool gnome-tool
But an error message appeared which reads unable to locate package unity-tweak-tool
Unable to locate gnome-tool

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Is this a boot problem or an apt error problem?

Comment: this is a mess......... title is about boot problem, question is about the mistake in typing gnome-tweak-tool and the question "tag" is kernel. All 3 , none is related to each other , lol. I guess we wait a bit until you edit your question and tell us which is actually the problem before we simply guess that your problem is just typing wrong the command.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title doesn't match the question body.
However from your previous questions, you have just finished installing Ubuntu. Now you can remove your USB and boot normally.

Coming to tweak-tool, even I couldn't find gnome-tool. Its gnome-tweak-tool.
While installing packages from apt-get, the first step to do is,

1. Update your local package index using `sudo apt-get update`.
2. Use bash-completion key (tab) after typing partial text of whole word to find correct name package.

   sudo apt-get install bash-completion

then do:
`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-` press tab here. It will give list of packages with similar name.

Or

3. Use `apt-cache search "package-name"`  (without quotes).eg: `apt-cache search unity-tweak-tool`. It will return the description of that package. You can use tab key here also.

The last type will help you to find whether certain package exist or not.

Comment: Thanks so much and I apologize for the complexity I pose, please just give some time to get familiar with the environment like I said earlier just moved from Windows based systems and its my first time in all these. Thank you.

Comment: Well @Anointed, it is good to know you are trying out Ubuntu. But only few will check on your profile to understand what exactly you need to know. It is better to change the question title asap or immediately to something like "unable to locate package" error. And this forum has lots of similar or exact questions and answers that you need. And welcome to askubuntu community, don't feel bad for any down votes. Instead improve the content of question or answer you provide as well as gain knowledge. Good luck.